# Box a matrix row

Tags: matrices, arrows, vertical, box

[image: matrix]

I'd like to get this image in LaTeX, I don't know how to box rows and to do the vertical arrow.

Comment: Welome to TeX SX! With the boxes flowing outside the determinant?

Comment: Not essential, I tried with simple commands and it's difficult. Thanks!

Comment: It is very easy with `pstricks`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nicematrix`. This package will create a node under each cell of the matrix and then, you can draw what you want with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
$\begin{vNiceMatrix}
\strut a & b & c \\
\strut d & e & f \\
\strut g & h & i 
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture} 
[inner xsep = 2mm , inner ysep = 0.1mm , outer sep = 3mm]
\node [draw, fit = (1-1) (1-3)] (L1) { } ; 
\node [draw, fit = (3-1) (3-3)] (L3) { } ; 
\draw [<->] (L1.west) -- (L3.west) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{vNiceMatrix}
= -
\begin{vmatrix}
\strut g & h & i \\
\strut d & e & f \\
\strut a & b & c
\end{vmatrix}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As the package name suggests: nice!

Answer (score 3):

One out of many possible ways to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzpicture}[mmat/.style={matrix of math nodes,
    inner sep=0pt,nodes={inner sep=2pt},column sep=2pt,row sep=2pt,
left delimiter=|,right delimiter=|},node distance=1ex]
\matrix[mmat](mat1){ a & b & c\\
d & e & f \\ g & h & i\\
};
\node[right=of mat1](eq){$=-$};
\matrix[mmat,right=of eq](mat2){ g & h & i\\
d & e & f \\ 
a & b & c\\
};
\node[fit=(mat1-1-1)(mat1-1-3),draw,inner xsep=2ex,yshift=2pt](F1){};
\node[fit=(mat1-3-1)(mat1-3-3),draw,inner xsep=2ex,inner ysep=1pt,yshift=-2pt](F2){};
\draw[latex-latex] ([xshift=-1em]F1.west) -- ([xshift=-1em]F2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading about tikz I'm just a beginner. Lots to learn!

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility with `pstricks`: the extremities of the first and last rows are defined as nodes, and connected via a node connection `\ncbox` with the relevant parameters, within a standard `vmatrix` environment, then the upper and lower left nodes connected  with `\ncarc`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

    \[ \begin{vmatrix}
         \Rnode{A}{a} & b & \Rnode{C}{c}\\
         d & e & f \\
         \Rnode{G}{g} & h & \Rnode{I}{i}
       \end{vmatrix} =
       - \begin{vmatrix}
            g & h & i \\
            d & e & f \\
            a & b & c
          \end{vmatrix}
        \psset{linewidth=0.4pt, boxsize=1.33ex, nodesep=0.8em, linearc=0.05}
        \ncbox{A}{C}
        \ncbox{G}{I}
        \ncarc[arrows=<->, arrowinset =0.12, offset=1.5em, nodesep=0, arcangle=15]{G}{A}
           \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]